# Testing the text content of a div in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I can't find a way to test the content of a div container in Ruby on Rails 4.

The following test is finding the right div :

```
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
```

but I can't figure how to test that some word (eg "Title") is included in the select.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Actually I used something like

```
assert_select 'div#error_explanation' do |elements|
    assert_match /Title/, elements.to_s
    assert_match /Blah/, elements.to_s
    assert_match /Foo/, elements.to_s
    assert_match /Bar/, elements.to_s
end
```

And it worked

Is that clean or can I do that cleaner ?

Comment: I wonder what the difference is betwee `to_s` and `to_html` https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb#L268-L291

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, this is the answer I solved the problem with.

```
assert_select 'div#error_explanation', "The form contains an error.", 4
```

assert_select 'div', 'whatever you want to look for inside the div', integer

use *assert_select* to select the div, then seperated by a comma, type in quotes what you are looking for. (in my case, i was looking for copy). I used another comma followed by a number because I wanted to find that copy in a div 4 times on the page.

There's a good article about more ways to use it here,
https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using `Test::Unit`. You should take a look at [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec).

With that, suppose you have an HTML like this -

```
<div id="error-explanation">
  Invalid email
</div>
```

You could write assertions like -

```
assert page.has_selector?("div#error_explanation", text: 'Invalid email')
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: I'm actually not using Capybara but the standard tests of RoR (Minitest I assume - I'm still a newbie not always knowing what I'm doing)

Comment: You should definitely try `Capybara`. It works with all major testing frameworks. You can write cleaner tests! If you can put here the kind of output HTML you are expecting, I might be able to help better :)